# Exclusive records MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have many ClientIDs to many pageids

Eg.

ClientID 1 PageID 3 
ClientID 1 PageID 1 
ClientID 2 PageID 3 
ClientID 2 PageID 2 
ClientID 3 PageID 3

In a query I want to bring up the record with only PageID 3 and PageID 2 exclusively.

So in my result I should get Client 2 and 3 and client 1 should be omitted out of the results... What's the best way to do this?

Answer:

```
SELECT clientID, clientName, pageID, profileTypeID, pageName
FROM  client
GROUP BY
  clientID
HAVING
  COUNT(*) = COUNT(IF(profileTypeID != 1, profileTypeID, NULL))
```

Comment: Sorry,I don't understand your example : ( Why do you exclude clientid 1 and include clientdid 3?

Comment: I'm presuming that ClientID = 2 should be returned because there is no other row associated with PageID = 2. However, why should ClientID=3 be returned when ClientID=1 is also associated with PageID = 3?

Answer (score 2):

The way I'm reading this is that you want any row where the given ClientID is not associated with a Page other than 2 or 3.

```
Select ...
From MyTable As T
Where T.PageID In(2,3)
    And Not Exists  (
                    Select 1
                    From MyTable As T2
                    Where T2.ClientID = T.ClientId
                        And T2.PageID Not In(2,3)
                    )
```